# Flutter_Swiper text over image

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have started playing around with Flutter Swiper (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper) and so far it is very powerful!

The only thing I can't make it do is overlay the text on the image. Here is my code with the text displayed below the image:

```
            new Swiper(
              outer: false,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          child: new Container(
                            child: new Image.asset(dateIdeas[index]),
                          ),
                        ),
                        new Text(
                          "test",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              itemCount: dateIdeas.length,
              layout: SwiperLayout.DEFAULT,
              itemHeight: 800,
              itemWidth: 400,
            ),
```

This displays the word "Test" below the image, and the text moves as the image is swiped. However I cannot make the text overlay on the image. I have tried adding padding and increasing the "bottom" value to shift the text up but it does not move. Annoyingly it does shift the text left, right and down when asked.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Is the text "Test" static? It doesn't change while sliding?

Comment: No, in the final version the text would not be static. Test is just a place holder. The text will relate to the image shown.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Stack`

```
    Swiper(
          outer: false,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          child: new Image.asset(dateIdeas[index]),
                        ),
                        new Text(
                          "test",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          // itemCount: dateIdeas.length,
          // layout: SwiperLayout.DEFAULT,
          itemHeight: 800,
          itemWidth: 400,
        );
```